# Only One Resolution in Ubuntu 640 x 480

Tags: drivers, wireless, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

I am completely new to Ubuntu and I want to change my resolution as everything is so big that even navigating this site is a pain. I am running a GTX 1080 and when I check display options there is only one drop down option and that is 640 x 480. Is this a driver issue? Because this is what Windows did before I installed the driver. I did try to install the nvidia drivers b following a tutorial I found on gogle but when I put in a command my screen turned blue. Then after a restart the problem with the resolution persisted and I am ONLY able to get a more suitable resolution when starting through recovery mode. Also what is weird is my wifi dongle does not work anymore as if the installation of the GPU drivers did something. I need to know what.

Answer (score 1):

Install the `nvidia-367` driver.

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-367
```

After that reboot your computer.

You may have to run `Additional Drivers` from `Software & Updates` to change to the best option.  Select the **recommended** or **tested** option.  After applying the changes, reboot.